# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I'm using C# and have an error:
`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion'`

```cs
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;
    
    namespace Infrastructure
    {
        public class BotContext : DbContext 
        {
            public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
                => options.UseMySql("server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;Connect Timeout=5;");
    
            public class Server
            {
                public ulong Id { get; set; }
                public string Prefix { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What NuGet package are you using? I think you are using [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), but instantiating it using [the documentation by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html), so choose [one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) or the [other](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore)...

Comment: Yes, using Pomelo.I rewrote the code as in the Pomelo documentation, but the code still doesn't work(same error)

`protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
                "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;Connect Timeout=5;"
            );
        } `

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/7.2.php

Comment: ??? The docs and the link you give clearly show a _second_ argument you need to pass... you seem to keep missing that.

Comment: Hah, really helped! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class BotContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    public BotContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
            "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;Connect Timeout=5;",
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 11))
        );
    }

    public class Server
    {
        public ulong Id { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This should help: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/7.2.php

Comment: Would you mind finding a link to something similar in English?

Comment: https://entityframework-extensions.net/efcore-pomelo-mysql-provider - similar to metanit(rus site)

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, new version of `Pomelo` needs more arguments. A simple solution is to add an empty `Version` class like this in startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDB>(options =>
                   options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version())));
```

**Update 2022 .Net 6**
Now we don't have `startup.cs` so add this to `program.cs` :

```
string? connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));


var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: thanks. worked for me when updating the pomelo nuget

Comment: thank it worked on my migration from dotnet core 3.1 to 6

Comment: Thanks for noticing the change in .NET 6